# XPATH Firebug filter does not filter as expected

Tags: xpath

Basically I have a list of presidents and I am only interested in the Nixon link and not Clinton or Obama.
What I find is that filtering as I have done returns the correct number of presidents (ie 1 in this case) but returns ALL of the a links instead of just the one for Nixon.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" name="obama"></a> <div class="headlineBlock">
<h2>Obama</h2>
<p class="tudor"><strong>Conditions:</strong> Always sunny </p>
<table class="resultGrid"><tr> <td class="first">
<h4><a href="http://www.thelinkiwant.com?params" title="Click to view result"</a></h4>
<a href="#" name="nixon"></a> <div class="headlineBlock">
<h2>Nixon</h2>
<p class="nixon"><strong>Conditions:</strong> Sometimes late </p>
<table class="resultGrid"><tr> <td class="first">
<h4><a href="http://www.thelinkiwant.com/?params" title="Click to view result"</a></h4>
<a href="#" name="clinton"></a> <div class="headlineBlock">
<h2>Clinton</h2>
<p class="tudor"><strong>Conditions:</strong> Never rainy </p>
<table class="resultGrid"><tr> <td class="first">
<h4><a href="http://www.thelinkiwant/?params" title="Click to view result"</a></h4>
```

XPATH:

```
$x("//div[@class='headlineBlock']/h2[not(contains('|Clinton|Obama|',concat('|',.,'|') ))]//../../table/a/@href")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your example.

There brackets missing after ever single "Click to view result", your "headlineBlock" divs and tables aren't closed, etc. So first you should make sure that your data is well formatted.

[W3C's Xml Validator can help with that](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp)

Your XPath looks mostly ok, I think the issue is with the `//` at the end - they are a bit too early. Try this instead:

```
//div[@class='headlineBlock']/h2[not(contains('|Clinton|Obama|',concat('|',.,'|') ))]/..//a/@href
```

> //div[@class='headlineBlock']

All divs of class headlineBlock ...

> /h2[not(contains('|Clinton|Obama|',concat('|',.,'|') ))]

... that don't contain certain terms.

> /..

Up one level (now we are at div `headlineBlock` again)

> //a

Any direct descendants of element type `a`

> /@href

H-Ref Attribute

Comment: which might be due to the messed up structure of your data - get that fixed and it will work. Otherwise you will have to work with other selectors like `[last()-1]` `following` etc. The current structure is not XML compliant and can therefore be interpreted differently depending on your parser implementation.